# Blob Detection in openCV works well, but for some reason it fails for a specific image

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

I have managed to find circles quite easily thank to the built-in functionality of SimpleBlobDetector_create in openCV (4.2.0.34), I made sure the background would be white for easy recognition. 
In the following image, 3 circles were found as I would expect:
[image]
**But for some reason strangely when I apply the same code on the image below,**

[image]

**This perfect circle doesn't get recognized. how come??**

here below is my short code.

```
img = cv2.imread(filename='img1.png')

cv2.imshow(winname="Original", mat=img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# set Circularity filtering parameters:
params.filterByCircularity = True
# 1 being perfect circle, 0 the opposite
params.minCircularity = 0.8

# create a detector with parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(parameters=params)

keypoints = detector.detect(img)

print("Number of circular Blobs: " + str(len(keypoints)))
```

Thank you all for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code here and got the same results. But adding

```
params.filterByArea = False
```

before `params.filterByCircularity = True` fixed the problem. This is kind of strange because I would expect that all the other attributes from `SimpleBlobDetector` would start with `False` as default. Also, after the change the code started to respond with 4 circles (which seems correct to me) and not 3 as previously.

[image: Match 4 circles]

Comment: Thank you!! I was sure by default this property would be set to false.